# Find all the complex numbers $z$ satisfying

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find all the complex numbers $z$ satisfying
>   $$
>   \bigg|\frac{1+z}{1-z}\bigg|=1
> $$

So far I´ve done this:
$$
  z=a+bi \\
  \bigg|\frac{(1+a)+bi}{(1-a)-bi}\bigg|=1 \\
  \mathrm{expression*conjugated} \\
  \bigg|\frac{1+2bi-(a^2)-(b^2)}{1+2a+a^2+b^2}\bigg|=1
$$

Comment: You should see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to better format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Good for you for trying $z=a+bi$.  We get a number of complex variable problems where the poster says "I have no idea".  This is an idea.  It works sometimes, not always, but if you have no other idea you should try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf{My\; Solution}::$ Given $$\displaystyle \left|\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right| = 1\Rightarrow \left|1+z\right| = |1-z| = |z-1|.$$

Now Put $z=x+iy\;,$ Then $$|x+iy+1|=|x+iy-1|$$

So we get $$\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} = \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}\Rightarrow (x+1)^2=(x-1)^2$$.

So we get $x=0$. So all Complex no. are in the form of $z=iy\;,$ where $y\in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: But the | | marks are for absolute value or module?. The problem doesn´t say. Should i asume its module?

Answer (score 4):

the relation
$$
\displaystyle \left|\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right| = 1
$$
expresses the fact that $z$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining $-1$ to $+1$. this is the imaginary axis

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $|c/d|=|c|/|d|$ and your numerator and denominator then represent the distances from ??????

Comment: but the | | marks are for absolute value or module?. The problem doesn´t say. Should i asume its module?

Comment: For complex numbers it is modulus.  $|z|=\sqrt {z\overline z}$  If $z$ is real you get the same result as absolute value.

Comment: The absolute value is just for real numbers! Module or complex absolute value is for all complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, $z=a+bi$, and $|z+1|=|1-z|=|z-1|$ (with $z \not= 1$). Hence $(a+1)^{2} +b^{2}=(a-1)^{2}+b^{2}$.
Therefore $a=0$ and $$z=bi \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{for any} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,b\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: But the | | marks are for absolute value or module?. The problem doesn´t say. Should i asume its module?

Comment: That is a standard notation. If it were any thing else they should mentioned that.